# How to stop neutered male cat from mounting the other one?

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression, multi-pet-families, dominance

I have two neutered male cats that sometimes exhibit dominance behaviors. I've had them both for about 5 years, and they go between cuddling, ignoring each other, and trying to be dominant multiple times throughout the day.

Cat A has stopped actually attacking Cat B, which is great. However, his new solution is to jump on Cat B, mount him, bite the back of Cat B's neck with his teeth, and stand there thrusting. Cat B just growls and cries throughout this until I clap at them to break it up.

(Note that Cat A is *mostly* the dominant cat, but Cat B tends to be in some situations and often growls and hisses when Cat A approaches him. Other times Cat B lies on Cat A and aggressively grooms him for hours, growling if Cat A tries to move at all. Cats are weird.)

Is there any solution to stopping this other than breaking it up when I see/hear it happening? Cat B doesn't seem to actually be getting hurt, but it's definitely annoying to him and it keeps interrupting my work calls.

Comment: I never heard of cats mounting each other as a display of dominance. The neck bite is clearly sexual behavior. Are you certain that both testicles of Cat A are removed? I suggest a check-in with a vet to make sure he doesn't still have a testicle (maybe internal) or some problem with his reproductive organs that cause him to act like that.